# Is it possible to add Avalonia controls to a Microsoft WPF application?

Tags: wpf, controls, avalonia

And if it is possible, how can it be organized?

I tried adding the control package as described on the [site](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/controls/datagrid), but it didn't work. Do Avalonia controls only work in Avalonia templates or they can be connected to Microsoft WPF?

Comment: [I don't think so: despite them both using XAML, Avalonia's documentation says their templated-controls have a different inheritance hiearchy compared to WPF's](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/misc/wpf/uielement-frameworkelement-and-control) - so existing compiled DLLs for one can't be loaded into an environment for the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, while it is possible to [host some controls from WPF in Avalonia](https://reference.avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia.Controls/NativeControlHost/) (in a Windows only manner), the inverse is not the case.  To do so would require WPF to add an interoperability host, like it has for WinForms, and WPF isn't receiving such updates anymore.